# Ionic3 input not selectable

Tags: ionic-framework, input, ionic3

**ionic-angular 3.9.2**

I have a login page like the following, which is loaded at startup when the user is not logged in.
The thing is that neither the username/e-mail, nor the password field can be selected until either of the followin is done:
- open the side menu, then close it
- navigate to another tab, navigate back to login
- tap the input field very often over a long period of time (up to 30 seconds)

```
<ion-header title="login">
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>{{"loginPage.title"|translate}}</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
    <form #loginForm="ngForm" novalidate>
        <ion-list no-lines>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating color="primary">{{"loginPage.username"|translate}}</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="login.username" name="username" type="email" #username="ngModel" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off"
                 required>
                </ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <p ion-text [hidden]="username.valid || submitted == false" color="danger" padding-left>{{"loginPage.usernameRequired"|translate}}
            </p>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating color="primary">{{"loginPage.password"|translate}}</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="login.password" name="password" type="password" #password="ngModel" required>
                </ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <p ion-text [hidden]="password.valid || submitted == false" color="danger" padding-left>
                {{"loginPage.passRequired"|translate}}
            </p>
        </ion-list>
        <button ion-button (click)="onLogin(loginForm)" type="submit" block>{{ "loginPage.login" | translate }}</button>
    </form>
    <div></div>
    <div padding>
        <a class="item" href="#" (click)="onSignup()">{{ "loginPage.signup" | translate }}</a>
    </div>
    <div padding>
        <a class="item" href="#" (click)="onForgotPassword()">{{ "loginPage.forgotPassword" | translate }}</a>
    </div>
    <div padding>
        <a class="item" href="#" (click)="onVerify()">{{ "loginPage.verification" | translate }}</a>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Any clues about how to fix this? Because i'm looking through google and the ionic forums for over 1 hour now and cannot find anything which solves the problem...

**EDIT:**

I found a little hack that works by removing the class input-cover from the elements. But that feels dirty...

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.input-cover');
for(let i in elements)
{
  if(elements[i].classList)
  elements[i].classList.remove('input-cover');
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity what is this inside of your ion-input: #password=etc. This does not sound standard. Also can you replace your code with default example from v3 docs and check if input focus behavior is fine?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko it's an Angular template reference variable. [Take a look here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-)

Comment: so yes template vars are known, but why would something be assigned to it in your case? template var refers template element

Comment: see here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/forms/ i think you need to implement form with one of those approaches and just follow that to prevent issues

Answer (score 3):

On your app.module.ts put this code inside imports tag:

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
        platforms: {
            android: {
                activator: 'none'
            }
        },
        scrollAssist: false, autoFocusAssist: false
    })
```